# SQL Server function returns no value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I might be overlooking something here or it could be the lack of coffee this am... I have a SQL Server function I'm trying to create and have it spit out results.

This is my code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_top_forms] ()
RETURNS @topforms TABLE 
                  (
                      -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
                      clicks varchar(50),
                      title varchar(150), 
                      urlpath varchar(max)
                  )
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @clicks as varchar(50)
  DECLARE @title varchar(150)
  DECLARE @urlpath varchar(max)
  DECLARE @everyone_relevant as bit

  IF @everyone_relevant = 1
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @topforms 
          SELECT TOP (10) clicks, title, url
          FROM dbo.view_all_forms
          ORDER BY clicks DESC
  END

  RETURN
END
```

My issue is that its not returning any values but I know in the `view_all_forms`, there is indeed data there. I'm using this in new query to return the results, it has the columns but no data. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I don't see that `@everyone_relevant` ever gets set to `1`. So it's just falling through the code.

Comment: And be very careful here. What you have is a multi-statement table valued function which is usually even slower than a scalar function. Consider making this an inline table valued function instead by removing all those extra variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, looks like I just didnt have the thing set write... Note to self, DRINK MORE coffee in the am.

Comment: sounds like you need some sleep.